# Destring variables with fractions

Tags: stata

I have string variables in my data that contain fractions and non-integers.

For example:

```
3 2/3 
8 1/2
 1.65
6 1/4
0.235
```

Stata cannot destring these variables with the `destring` command.

Is there anything I can do to convert my string variables to numeric so I can use them for analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code, while extending to cases like " 3 2/3" or "- 6 1/4" (notice the spaces), might also be useful for saving some typings.

```
replace var1 = subinstr(var1, "- ", "-",.)
split var1, generate(x) destring force

egen y = ends(var1) if strmatch(var1,"*/*"), last
split y, destring force p("/")

replace x1 = cond(x1<0, x1-y1/y2, cond(x1!=.,x1+y1/y2, y1/y2)) if y1!=.
keep var1 x1
```